# filter default folder from Mailkit/IMailFolder

Tags: c#, winforms, mailkit

I am trying to get all required folder using Mailkit/IMailFolder. It gives me some unwanted folder like "Calendar, Contacts etc.", Is there any good way to filter that folder? because in such folder there is no email available and it is no use for me also it is not created by me it is default folders.

I am using folder.GetSubfolders(false) method in c#. below is my code.

```
static List<IMailFolder> GetFolders(IMailFolder personal = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (personal == null)
            {
                personal = MailManager.Instance.ImapClient.GetFolder(MailManager.Instance.ImapClient.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
            }
            return personal.GetSubfolders(false).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code snippet (which uses LINQ):

```
return personal.GetSubfolders (false).Where (x => X.Name != "Calendar" && x.Name != "Contacts").ToList ();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                                                                                                           I want to know, Do we have any property available in IMailFolder which differentiate folder created by user and default?

Comment: Nope, because the IMAP protocol does not have any such property either.